# pymongo default database connection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to connect to MongoDB from my Python code, the only thing I have is a url. Per [mongo URL doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) I can specify database name:

```
mongodb://host/db_name
```

Now I would like to use exactly database specified from URL and don't want to parse it manually to extract name of database. But `MongoClient` have no interface to access default one. Any thoughts how to manage this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

PyMongo/MongoClient provides a `get_default_database()` method:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://host/db_name")
db = client.get_default_database()
```

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

Comment: get_default_database() is deprecated(), use get_database() instead

Comment: get_default_database() has been undeprecated since 3.8

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

Changed in version 3.8: Undeprecated. Added the default, codec_options, read_preference, write_concern and read_concern parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pymongo.uri_parser.parse_uri for this:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 12 2013, 14:44:36) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> uri = "mongodb://user:pass@example.com/my_database/?w=2"
>>> from pymongo.uri_parser import parse_uri
>>> parse_uri(uri)
{'username': 'user', 'nodelist': [('example.com', 27017)], 'database': 'my_database/',
'collection': None, 'password': 'pass', 'options': {'w': 2}}
```

In PyMongo 2.6 there will be a get_default_database() method for this. See [PYTHON-461](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-461)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error from Dan's answer:

```
OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

#### Solution

I realized I needed to specify the authentication source as there is authentication to my instance. If you face the same, use this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>/<DEFAULT_DATABASE>?authSource=admin")
db = client.get_default_database()

# Then you may query
db["my_col"].find_one({})
```

Fill `<USERNAME>`, `<PASSWORD>`, `<HOST>`, `<DEFAULT_DATABASE>` accordingly (read more about [MongoDB connection strings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)).

You may have the `authSource` in another database but I think `admin` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't work at all. When starting  `pymongo` dumps warning:

> UserWarning: database name or authSource in URI is being ignored.